# In this Java scenario, how can you avoid calling a wildcard method with data whose type is only known at run-time?

Tags: java

I've been making a Java program which involves manipulating a collection of dynamically created, heterogeneously-typed data stored in a container, and I've been running into the following small conundrum which, while I've tried to get around it with hacks before, have never felt very satisfied with them.

In the GUI part of the program, we must present the data to the user. When it comes across a field with a given type, it needs to produce a view for data of that type. To make it extensible (Open/Closed Principle) to new types of data without modifying the GUI window class and instead just adding new handler objects to produce new kinds of views, my GUI class has a member like this:

```
private HashMap<Class<?>, IViewGenerator<?>> mViewGenerators;
```

where the `IViewGenerator<T>` is an interface to an object which generates view for data of type `T`, a generic interface:

```
interface IViewGenerator<T> {
     View generate(T val); // generic method
}
```

This way, I can call a "`addViewGenerator`" method or the like on the GUI object to add new value type support by composition and thus in an "open/closed" fashion.

The problem is this. In the same class as `mViewGenerators` we'll have something like

```
private void buildView() {
     ...
     for(Object data : heterogeneousDataSet) {
          Class<?> dataClass = data.getClass();
          if(mViewGenerators.containsKey(dataClass)) {
               // Wanna make a view for this data based on its type,
               // but this is illegal Java
               View v = mViewGenerators.get(dataClass).generate(data);

               // add the view to the growing GUI
               ...
          }
     }
     ...
}
```

You can see what the issue here is. Note that one could potentially use a hack like reflection but as I just said, seems like a hack and a code smell.

Hence, what's the better way to design or approach this that would not have this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have for adding a new view generator and getting the view generator.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. The `IViewGenerator` interface concrete classes all have methods with the same names.  What is the compiler problem?  As @Progman said, edit your question to include a [mre] illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc : Tried. Does it help now?

Answer (score 2):

Java's type system doesn't handle this well, so you'll need to break away from it to some degree — which will probably still feel a bit hacky, unfortunately. However, you can isolate it to a single method, and use `@SuppressWarnings` to quiet down the compiler's warnings.

I would do it as something like this:

```java
private static <T> View generateFrom(Class<?> cls, IViewGenerator<?> generator, Object data)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<T> classT = (Class<T>) cls;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    IViewGenerator<T> generatorT = (IViewGenerator<T>) generator;
                                                                                              
    T dataT = classT.cast(data);
    return generatorT.generate(dataT);
}
```

What this does is:

- specifies some `T`, without really caring much what it is
- casts the `Class<?>` to a `Class<T>`. This is unchecked, but we suppress that warning.
- similarly casts the `IViewGenerator<?>` to `IViewGenerator<T>`
- does a runtime cast of the data to `T`. This *will* get checked at runtime, and if the data isn't of the correct type (namely, `cls`'s type), it'll throw a ClassCastException.

  - The ClassCastException is a feature, not a bug. ;) Without it, if the types don't match, you'll get a ClassCastException within the generator's `generate()`, likely at a line that looks "impossible" (at first glance) to generate a ClassCastException, and possibly even in some lower-down library call. It can be very confusing: best to catch it here.
  - I recommend keeping this as a separate call (not inlining it to the next line), so that if that exception gets thrown, it's nice and obvious what's causing it.
- then, passes that casted data into the casted generator

This works as long as the IViewGenerator's `T` is the same as the given Class's.

Beyond that, what I might suggest is to have the `IViewGenerator` supply its own Class:

```java
public interface IViewGenerator<T extends IViewable>
{
    Class<T> dataClass();
    View generate(T val);
}
```

With that, the method becomes:

```java
private static <T> View generateFrom(IViewGenerator<?> generator, Object data)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    IViewGenerator<T> generatorT = (IViewGenerator<T>) generator;
                                                                                
    T dataT = generatorT.dataClass().cast(data);
    return generatorT.generate(dataT);
}
```

You still need the `Map<Class<?>, IViewGenerator<?>>` to find the correct generator, but once you have that generator, you don't need the map's key anymore.

The main advantage of this approach is that you don't need to worry about the `Class<?>` and `IViewGenerator<?>` matching up (that is, referring at runtime to the same `T`). The IViewGenerator supplies its own Class, which is much easier to make sure matches with its `generate()` (the only way to have it *not* match would be to use a raw type in the `implements` clause: `class EvilViewGenerator implements IViewGenerator`).

It similarly simplifies the creation of the Map: rather than hard-coding the class-to-generator mappings, you just pass in a collection of generators, and then populate the map based on each generator's self-reported Class.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination: They serve as hints to the compiler to warn/error out when generics says it cannot work, and to inject casts to tie it all together, and *that is it* - what you want to do here is a fairly common job (there is a 'link' between the key and the value) but **generics simply cannot do that** - it's not expressive enough.

### The simple solution

You're in good company - `ArrayList.java` itself does the same thing: Use generics in the 'outside facing' parts of your API to ensure callers can't mess up without the compiler telling them about it, but ignore generics within your API: Use raw types and `@SuppressWarnings` your way around them. Looks a bit like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface View {}

interface ViewGenerator<T> {
    View generate(T arg);
}

public class ViewGeneratorManager {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") private final Map viewGenerators = new HashMap();
    
    public <T> void register(Class<T> type, ViewGenerator<T> generator) {
        if (type == null) throw new NullPointerException("type");
        if (generator == null) throw new NullPointerException("generator");
        
        if (type.isInterface()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only concrete types can be registered");
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Object v = viewGenerators.putIfAbsent(type, generator);
        
        if (v != null) throw new IllegalStateException("There is already a ViewGenerator registered for type " + type);
    }
    
    /** @throws IllegalStateException If {@code type} has no generator registered for it */
    public <T> ViewGenerator<T> getGenerator(Class<T> type) throws IllegalStateException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ViewGenerator<T> generator = (ViewGenerator<T>) viewGenerators.get(type);
        
        if (generator == null) throw new IllegalStateException("No ViewGenerator registered for type: " + type);
        return generator;
    }

    /** @throws IllegalStateException If {@code type} has no generator registered for it */
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public View process(Object obj) throws IllegalStateException {
        Class<?> t = obj.getClass();
        while (t != null) {
            ViewGenerator vg = getGenerator(t);
            if (vg != null) return vg.generate(obj);
            t = t.getSuperclass();
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException("No ViewGenerator registered for type: " + obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

From the point of view of *users* of this class, all is well: Generics ensure that somebody can't, say, register a ViewGenerator that requires `String` arguments, for the `Integer` type, and ViewGenerator implementations don't have to bother writing casts or `instanceof` checks.

Given that generics are *solely* a compiler-checking thing (they do nothing whatsoever at runtime), if you are satisfied that the code isn't going to cause type problems, then therefore that's good enough.

### The complex solution

You can't try to link some generics in the 'key' type of a `Map` with some generics in the `Value` type of a map, that's simply not a thing that you can do. However, you can link types within a single `Container` class. However, this mostly kicks the can down the road: Within a container you can now have generics-powered type safety too, but how do you go from a given type to its container, and then pass this thing to that container with generics protecting you?

Hence, why the simple solution is almost always the best solution. The simple solution is easy enough to understand and has exactly the API you want to expose.

But, if you want to look further, here is a completely different approach that may not even fit your needs:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public abstract class ViewGenerator<T> {
    public Class<T> getType() {
        Class<?> me = this.getClass();
        while (me != null) {
            Class<?> sc = me.getSuperclass();
            if (sc == ViewGenerator.class) return extractType(sc.getGenericSuperclass());
            me = sc;
        }
        
        throw new RuntimeException("ViewGenerator is not in your hierarchy; that doesn't seem possible: " + getClass();
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked", "cast"})
    private Class<T> extractType(Type sc) {
        if (sc instanceof ParameterizedType pt) {
            Type[] tArgs = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
            if (tArgs.length == 1 && tArgs[0] instanceof Class z) return (Class<T>) z;
        }
        
        throw new RuntimeException("Either manually override `getType()`, or ensure you extend `ViewGenerator<ConcreteClass>`");
    }
}
```

This setup just requires that you write `class StringViewGenerator extends ViewGenerator<String> {}` and don't need to do much more; you can use this in combination with the API to make the experience even simpler for the callers.